# std::wstring length

Tags: c++, string, encoding, std, utf-16

What is the result of std::wstring.length() function, the length in wchar_t(s) or the length in symbols? And why?

```
TCHAR r2[3];
r2[0] = 0xD834;  // D834, DD1E - musical G clef
r2[1] = 0xDD1E;  //
r2[2] = 0x0000;  // '/0'

std::wstring r = r2;

std::cout << "capacity: " << r.capacity() << std::endl;
std::cout << "length: "   << r.length()   << std::endl;
std::cout << "size: "     << r.size()     << std::endl;
std::cout << "max_size: " << r.max_size() << std::endl;

Output>

capacity: 351
length: 2
size: 2
max_size: 2147483646
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`std::wstring::size()` returns the number of wide-char elements in the string. This is not the same as the number of characters (as you correctly noticed).

Unfortunately, the `std::basic_string` template (and thus its instantiations, such as `std::string` and `std::wstring`) is encoding-agnostic. In this sense, it is actually just a template for a string of bytes and not a string of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly std::wstring is an instantiation of `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >`.

Although most of the real work is done by char_traits, and one can write their own, this is done primarily to enable use of the C runtime library with different character sizes.

The way to parse in a pointer of Element* is until the character indicated by the char_traits as the terminator is reached.

However you can construct with a pointer and a length, in which case it will read the number of characters it tells you to, which will include any null-bytes. You may have embedded null-bytes in a basic_string, and if you call length() or size() which are aliases for the same thing, it will tell you how many characters it contains.

There is no magic in char_traits to decode multi-element characters as one, nor should you try to implement it that way.

Comment: and why exactly was this answer marked down? I gave useful information about exactly what a wstring is and how it gets constructed from a pointer.

Comment: I for one think it is an excellent answer, particularly your explanation of the use of char_traits' terminator character.

Answer (score 0):

size method returns the current number of elements in the string. It is the same as wstring::length
People usually talk about a word, sentence or paragraph's length, not its size

Comment: size_type string::capacity() const

Returns the number of characters a string can hold without reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

`length()` and `size()` typically return the number of "characters" (irrespective of width) in the string *excluding* the `null`, here the length & size is 2. `capacity()` returns how much memory (read: how many characters, as this is multi-byte) is typically available before the string will re-allocate.